Automatically reconnect to wireless display after failure
We have a ceiling mounted LS740HD projector back-projecting to a transparent screen pasted to our Information Centre front window. Because of cable length and placement restrictions, the projector uses a Microsoft Wireless Display adapter rather than an HDMI cable. The associated PC (Lenovo ThinkCentre, Windows 10) runs DigitalSignage SignPlayer and communicates with the projector via Miracast in duplicate mode. The line-of-sight PC to projector distance is about 3 metres. The PC's main monitor is an indoor TV connected via HDMI. I have implemented a script to automatically connect the projector and run at PC startup which does auto login. This copes with the occasional reboot of the PC. The digitalsignage software has a watchdog which deals with unexpected errors and presumably restarts its display sequence. The indoor TV display is fine.
So far so good, but this whole thing needs to run unattended. We get occasional and unexplained disconnections of the projector, which reverts to the MS connection home screen. This happens once or twice a day.
I need some periodically running task to check that the remote display is still connected, and re-connect if not. The piece I am missing is detecting that the wireless display is no longer connected. Powershell maybe? Or I have some coding skills. If so, it could probably replace this vbs solution I use for connecting too:
How to connect to a wireless Display adapter automatically through scripts or Task Scheduler?
An additional small irritation is that the display shows a connection taskbar which can apparently only be unpinned manually. I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to proceed.
